# Inserting value from Javascript to mysql if possible through php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm currently developing a intranet application for my company. Within my application i would like to fetch some variables with javascript and send them to a MySql database through php.

I know that javascript is a client-side and php is server-side so I'm not sure if it's even possible to transfer the variables through.

Goal is to get the current users computer name and store it in a SQL database whenever they are opening the intranet site.

```
<?php
  <script type="javascript">
    var network = new ActiveXObject('WScript.network');
    <?php $pcName = "<script>document.write(network.computername)</script>";
  </script>
?>
```

This part works perfectly. The computername is stored in the php variable `$pcName` and it shows fine on the intranet site when I try to echo the variable.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO t1 (pcName) VALUES ('".$pcName."')";
```

But when I insert it into my sql table the value is `"<script>document.write(network.computername)</script>"`.
Am I missing something? Or is it as I assumed that the variable is available on the clint, and the client only.

Comment: you can use cookie for that

Comment: when you say echo $pcName, you emit that `<script>...</script>` tag (the same as what you get in the database). Then, the browser evaluates it and displays the computer name, however that is client-only..

Comment: What you are missing is the understanding of what executes and when.  PHP is executed by the server, the JavaScript part of it is literal until it is rendered by the client then it becomes code.  What you need to do us use AJAX to send the client side data to a location on the server that the PHP can receive and do something with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to create and call an "API" of some sort. For example, you could have something like this on the client:

```
<script type="javascript">
    var network = new ActiveXObject('WScript.network');
    var pcName = network.computername;
    fetch('storeComputer.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            pcName: pcName
        })
    });
</script>
```

And then on PHP side:

```
// storeComputer.php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$pcName = $json['pcName'];
// do what you want with $pcName..
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, but i use jquery inside javascript to send the parameter to php. Its works for me very well

try this

```
$('.add_item').click(function(){
    var responsecontainer=$('#responsecontainer').val();   

    var ProductName=$('#ProductTable').val();
    $.ajax({
            url:"sample.php"
            , method:"POST"
            , data: {
                ProductName: ProductName,

            }
            , success: function(result){
                // do some thing here
          }
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
}
```

use can use some other method too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

Javascript can launch any URL with parameters, notably including JSON encoded parameters; the URL can launch a CGI script; the CGI script can catch the JSON and interact with the MySQl; and then return the result to javascript, either asynchronously or synchronously. Here's an asynch URL launch:

```
// this is asynchronous - result comes back to callback later, while this returns immediately
 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------=======------------
 function callAjax(url, callback)
 {
    var xmlhttp;
    // compatible with IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

.
Here's a callback:

```
function cb_myCallback(theStuff)
 {
     // process theStuff here. If it's JSON data, you can unpack it trivially in Javascript,
     // as I will describe later. For this example, it's just text. You're going to get
     // back "hello, Ben"
     console.log(theStuff);
 }
```

.
So here's how I might use that to call a script that can access the database:

```
function pyRequest(upd_data,upd_callback)
 {
 var cd_url;
    cd_url = '/cgi-bin/myPython.py?myData=' + encodeURIComponent(upd_data);
    callAjax(cd_url,upd_callback);
 }

pyRequest("Ben",cb_myCallback);
```

.
So here’s what happens. pyRequest() builds a URL that can call the Python (or whatever you like to use) script. callAjax() actually does the calling. This all returns immediately to the calling code. Later, when the script has completed whatever its task is, the callback, in the example cb_myCallback(), is sent whatever the script emitted.

**Synchronous Approach**

There may be times when you won’t want to use an asynchronous callback, because you can’t proceed until you have the data you asked for. In such cases, you need to use a synchronous request, which will not return (with the actual response) until the response has been received from the script. Note that in this function, I embed the URL to demonstrate a little variety in possible structuring of these types of usages:

```
// this is synchronous - result returns only when called script provides it
 // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 function syncCallAjax(spdq_myData)
 {
 var remote = '__Unset__';
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var remote_url;

    remote_url = '/cgi-bin/myPython.py?myData=' + encodeURIComponent(spdq_myData);
    request.open('GET', remote_url, false);  // false makes the request synchronous
    request.send(null);

    if (request.status === 200)
    {
        remote = request.responseText;
    }
    return(remote);
 }
```